# Combining groups in MongoDB - Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have this code in `MySQL` corresponding to a simple car database

```sql
SELECT
"Cost" AS "Metric",
AVG(car_cost) As "Avg",
MIN(car_cost) As "Min",
MAX(car_cost) As "Max",
"Dollars" As "Unit"
from db.car_data

union SELECT
'Mileage',
AVG(car_mileage),
MIN(car_mileage),
MAX(car_mileage),
'Miles'
from db.car_data
```

That returns this table

| Metric | Avg | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cost | 2345 | 5674 | 53456 |
| Mileage | 49023 | 53 | 178003 |

But, when recreate this in a `MongoDB` equivalent I run into an issue

```js
 db.car_data.aggregate([
  {"$group": 
    {
      _id: null,
      Avg: {
        $avg: { "$car_cost" }
      },
      Min: {
        $min: { "$car_cost" }
      },
      Max: {
        $max: { "$car_cost" }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$group": 
    {
      _id: null,
      Avg: {
        $avg: { car_mileage }
      },
      Min: {
        $min: { car_mileage }
      },
      Max: {
        $max: { car_mileage }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Actual Output**

```json
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "Avg": null,
    "Min": null,
    "Max": null
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```json
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "Avg": 2345,
    "Min": 5674,
    "Max": 53456
  },
  {
    "_id": null,
    "Avg": 49023,
    "Min": 53,
    "Max": 178003
  }
]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this with aggregation in Mongo? They each work in Mongo on their own...

Comment: Check this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/

Comment: they are 2 collections with the same name, but from different database? in one you used db, and in the other dbName, if its 1 collection from the same database, you can use 6 accumulators instead of 3, and with project change the results. we have `$facet` and `$unionWith` but doesn't seem to need any of those. If you really need 2 documents you can put them in 1 array(the 6 resuts)  with 2 members and unwind

Comment: @Takis_ thanks for pointing out this typo. They're supposed to be the same database. I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- you have 1 collection in 1 database, and you want 6 accumulators
- you can seperate them in groups of 3 or even in 2 documents to get the exact SQL like result

*we have `$facet` `$unionWith` etc but you dont need those, no need to do multiple aggregations, with only 1 you can get all you need.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K6T4SZ7NrlH)

```js
aggregate(
[ {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : null,
    "avg_cost" : {
      "$avg" : "$car_cost"
    },
    "min_cost" : {
      "$min" : "$car_cost"
    },
    "max_cost" : {
      "$max" : "$car_cost"
    },
    "avg_mileage" : {
      "$avg" : "$car_mileage"
    },
    "min_mileage" : {
      "$min" : "$car_mileage"
    },
    "max_mileage" : {
      "$max" : "$car_mileage"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$set" : {
    "array" : [ {
      "metric" : "cost",
      "avg" : "$avg_cost",
      "min" : "$min_cost",
      "max" : "$max_cost"
    }, {
      "metric" : "mileage",
      "avg" : "$avg_mileage",
      "min" : "$min_mileage",
      "max" : "$max_mileage"
    } ]
  }
}, {
  "$unwind" : {
    "path" : "$array"
  }
}, {
  "$replaceRoot" : {
    "newRoot" : "$array"
  }
} ]
)
```

Comment: Excellent explanation for exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your help!